# failed to retrieve accessToken from instagram with passportJS

Tags: passport.js, instagram, instagram-api

I am setting up my website with Passport-Instagram and I continue getting an error: "InternalOAuthError: Failed to obtain access token". I am simply trying to console.log my accessToken and my profile info when I try logging in but no matter which block of code I use whether it is jaredhansons GitHub for passport-instagram, I can not seem to obtain the access Token.

The first time that I used these setups it did actually redirect me to the Instagram login page but after the first time on a browser it just sends me this failed to obtain access token error.

I have tried using jared hanson's setup https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-instagram/blob/master/examples/login/app.js
I have tried using https://medium.com/crowdbotics/add-instagram-login-to-your-nodejs-app-using-passportjs-be7e8e31efb8

```
//passport.js file

  passport.use(new InstagramStrategy({
    clientID: keys.instagramClientID,
    clientSecret: keys.instagramClientSecret,
    callbackURL: '/auth/instagram/callback',
    proxy: true
  }, (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
     console.log(accessToken);
     console.log(profile);
    //User.findOrCreate({ instagramId: profile.id }, function (err, user) {
      return done(err, user);
    //});
  }
  ));
  passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
    done(null, user.id);
  });

  passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
    User.findById(id)
    .then(user => done(null, user));
  });


//auth.js file

router.get('/instagram', passport.authenticate('instagram'))

router.get('/instagram/callback', 
  passport.authenticate('instagram', { failureRedirect: '/' }),(req, res) => {
    res.redirect('/dashboard');
  });
```

I expect to console.log the accessToken given by Instagram.

GitHub repo: https://github.com/ValverdeDaniel/BRv2